# Is the RAM required to run Docker considered overhead or do docker processes make use of it?

Tags: docker, memory-management, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I'm trying to understand Docker memory utilization. [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/) state that the requirements are **2GB RAM, 3GB Disk, & a StaticIP**.

Does this mean that every machine that runs Docker will require 2GB *just to run Docker* (i.e. to run a docker image that needs 2GB, I need 4GB of RAM)?

Or, does this requirement mean that the images deployed need a minimum 2GB to run in a Docker environment?

I think it is the latter, but I need the community to answer definitively.

**EDIT:** Updated the Docker docs reference. The underlying question stands.

Comment: Those docs refer to UCP (Universal Control Plane, Docker's Enterprise management layer), not Docker itself. They are also super old.

Comment: @johnharris85 - I updated the link and I still wonder about this. Which docs should I be looking at?

Comment: Still UCP, which is not the daemon. And the former for UCP. For Docker itself, I have run it on machines with 512MB RAM and it works fine.